# Change Copy and Paste Icons in WP7 and Add Custom Menus like Copy and paste in Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to change Copy and Paste Icons in Windows Phone 7 and also wants to add custom menus like Copy and paste in Windows phone For example Highlight, and bookmark etc in Webbrowser control.

Q1: Can i generate copy like control when text selected.
Q2: Can i add circle icons when text selected.

I have tried the List and windows phone 7 toolbar's contextmenu but i want to use the same scheme for windows phone.

If someone has related information please help.

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a popup with Listbox

```
<Popup Name="textSelectionMenuPopup">

            <ListBox Name="textSelectionMenu" Margin="0,0,0,100" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource myLBStyle}" SelectionChanged="OnTextSelectionMenuSelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Copy">
                    <ListBoxItem.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/Copy.png"/>
                    </ListBoxItem.Background>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Highlights">
                    <ListBoxItem.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/Highlights.png"/>
                    </ListBoxItem.Background>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Tag">
                    <ListBoxItem.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/Tag.png"/>
                    </ListBoxItem.Background>
                </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Content="Note">
                    <ListBoxItem.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/Note.png"/>
                    </ListBoxItem.Background>
                </ListBoxItem>

            </ListBox>
        </Popup>
```

and Handle the OnTextSelectionMenuSelectionChanged

```
 void OnTextSelectionMenuSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        ListBox lstbox = sender as ListBox;

        if (lstbox.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            textSelectionMenuPopup.IsOpen = false;

            string command = (lstbox.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem).Content as string;

            switch (command)
            {
                case "Copy":

                    break;

                case "Highlights":

                    break;

                case "Tag":

                    break;

                case "Note":
                    break;

                case "cancel":
                    break;
            }
        }
```